# Nginx not started, homebrew says it is

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

brew services says nginx is started..

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Youri:Homebrew youri$ brew services start nginx
Service `nginx` already started, use `brew services restart nginx` to restart.
```

Same for launchctl

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Youri:Homebrew youri$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist 
/Users/youri/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist: service already loaded
```

My homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string>
        <string>-g</string>
        <string>daemon off;</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

brew services list says the following:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Youri:LaunchAgents youri$ brew services list
Name    Status  User  Plist
mariadb started youri /Users/youri/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx   error   youri /Users/youri/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php71   started youri /Users/youri/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php71.plist
```

The syntax is oke:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Youri:LaunchAgents youri$ plutil -lint homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist 
homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist: OK
```

When i run `sudo nginx` i can access my website

Comment: What makes you think it’s not started?

Comment: Because when i access ```localhost``` nothing shows up!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because nginx is going to start at port 80, it needs to be root. LaunchAgents are run as non-root user when that user logs in. [LaunchDaemons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/290946/348772) are loaded at boot as root user.

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Move the `homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist`

```
sudo mv ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

Load the plist from the LaunchDaemons folder

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Now, `sudo brew services list` shows a running nginx process

```
Name    Status  User  Plist
nginx   started root  /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Running `brew services list` without root will result in an error status, because you need to be root to read the status.

Comment: Ah, you found the answer by yourself.

Comment: The third command is giving "Path had bad ownership/permissions"

Comment: For me only 'launchctl unload/load' works, whereas 'lauchctl start/stop' fails to start any Nginx process.

Comment: I've tried. User shows "root" but the website is still not accessible.

Comment: @AkshaySoam then change ownership of file:
`/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` to be the same as the other files in the directory:
`sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist`

Comment: in brew services list it shows nginx error 256 for me

Comment: @muenalan correct. Same worked for me

Comment: "error 256" for me too.

Answer (score 4):

As said, this happens because port 80 is reserved, it needs to be allocated by root.

An easier way is run `brew services` with `sudo`

```
sudo brew services start nginx
```